# DatabaseError: unable to open database file on django

Tags: django, django-database

I have a **Django 1.5** application running on apache2 server and using **sqlite** database.

The setting for the database is as follow

```
DATABASES = {
   'default': {
       'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
       'NAME': '/var/www/html/project/devdb',
       'USER': '',
       'PASSWORD': '',
       'HOST': '',
       'PORT': '',
   }
}
```

where **devdb** is the database file generated.

When I run migration commands from the terminal console, it works fine and data is migrated to the database.

But when I visit the application URL, it gives the error

```
DatabaseError at /url_path/
attempt to write a readonly database
```

Then I change the permission of file using

```
sudo chown 777 devdb
```

Then it starts giving the error

```
DatabaseError at /url_path/
unable to open database file
```

`ls -la` gives following output for the `devdb` file

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 ubuntu ubuntu   1036 May 11  2018 manage.py
-rw-rw-r--  1 ubuntu ubuntu 291840 May 28 09:31 devdb
```

Getting `user` of the apache2 running using

```
ps -ef | egrep '(httpd|apache2|apache)' | grep -v `whoami` | grep -v root | head -n1 | awk '{print $1}'
```

gives `www-data`

But changing owner of the file to `www-data` again gives **unable to open database file**.

Comment: Django 1.5 is many years old, unsupported, and insecure. You should upgrade.

Comment: Sure. Since the application is huge code base, I'm writing it in latest version of Django.

Answer (score 0):

A sqlite db needs to be owned by www-data and so does the directory it is in.

So if your app is in `/var/www/app` do

```
cd /var/www
chown www-data:www-data app
cd app
chown ww-data:www-data devdb
```